# Handling a file with multiple processes and pthreads

Tags: c, synchronization, pthreads, semaphore

I'm having trouble with this exercise of synchronization between processes and threads. The main process should create **N** childs (making them start at roughly the same time) which should in turn create **M** threads. Now those threads must write on a file. After some time **T** the main thread should stop the child processes and call a function which will find which process made more accesses. It should not be important what will be written on the file or how the main process will decide which one wrote more.
The problem is: nothing is written. The file is created, but nothing happens and I cannot understand why. I wasted an afternoon on this and I still can't understand what's wrong ( altough I suspect sigaction, since I was not expected to use that to make child processes stop). Please help. Here is the code

*EDIT: The problem should not be in **init_file()** or **parseOutput()**, since they were given me by the professor, are tested and I left them unchanged*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>

// macros for error handling
#include "common.h"

#define N 10   // child process count
#define M 10   // thread per child process count
#define T 3     // time to sleep for main process

#define FILENAME    "accesses.log"
#define SEMFILENAME "/sem_file"
#define SEMPROCESSESNAME "/sem_proc"

/*
 * data structure required by threads
 */
typedef struct thread_args_s {
    unsigned int child_id;
    unsigned int thread_id;
} thread_args_t;

/*
 * parameters can be set also via command-line arguments
 */
int n = N, m = M, t = T;

/* TODO: declare as many semaphores as needed to implement
 * the intended semantics, and choose unique identifiers for
 * them (e.g., "/mysem_critical_section") */
sem_t * sem_file;
sem_t * sem_processes;
int running = 1;

/*
 * Create a named semaphore with a given name, mode and initial value.
 * Also, tries to remove any pre-existing semaphore with the same name.
 */
sem_t *create_named_semaphore(const char *name, mode_t mode, unsigned int value) {
    printf("[Main] Creating named semaphore %s...", name);
    fflush(stdout);

    // TODO
    sem_unlink(name);
    sem_t *ret;
    ret = sem_open(name, O_CREAT, mode, value);

    if(ret == SEM_FAILED)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "failed to open %s", name);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    printf("done!!!\n");
    return ret;
}

/*
 * Ensures that an empty file with given name exists.
 */
void init_file(const char *filename) {
    printf("[Main] Initializing file %s...", filename);
    fflush(stdout);
    int fd = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0600);
    if (fd<0) handle_error("error while initializing file");
    close(fd);
    printf("closed...file correctly initialized!!!\n");

    sem_file = create_named_semaphore(SEMFILENAME, 0777, 1);
}
/*
 * Child's signal handler
 */
void child_sig_handler(int signum) {
    running = 0;
}


void parseOutput() {
    // identify the child that accessed the file most times
    int* access_stats = calloc(n, sizeof(int)); // initialized with zeros
    printf("[Main] Opening file %s in read-only mode...", FILENAME);
    fflush(stdout);
    int fd = open(FILENAME, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0) handle_error("error while opening output file");
    printf("ok, reading it and updating access stats...");
    fflush(stdout);

    size_t read_bytes;
    int index;
    do {
        read_bytes = read(fd, &index, sizeof(int));
        if (read_bytes > 0)
            access_stats[index]++;
    } while(read_bytes > 0);
    printf("ok, closing it...");
    fflush(stdout);

    close(fd);
    printf("closed!!!\n");

    int max_child_id = -1, max_accesses = -1, i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("[Main] Child %d accessed file %s %d times\n", i, FILENAME, access_stats[i]);
        if (access_stats[i] > max_accesses) {
            max_accesses = access_stats[i];
            max_child_id = i;
        }
    }
    printf("[Main] ===> The process that accessed the file most often is %d (%d accesses)\n", max_child_id, max_accesses);
    free(access_stats);
}

void* thread_function(void* x) {
    thread_args_t *args = (thread_args_t*)x;

    /* TODO: protect the critical section using semaphore(s) as needed */
    if(sem_wait(sem_file)) handle_error("failed to wait on sem_file");
    // open file, write child identity and close file

    int fd = open(FILENAME, O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);
    if (fd < 0) handle_error("error while opening file");

    printf("[Child#%d-Thread#%d] File %s opened in append mode!!!\n", args->child_id, args->thread_id, FILENAME);   

    write(fd, &(args->child_id), sizeof(int));
    printf("[Child#%d-Thread#%d] %d appended to file %s opened in append mode!!!\n", args->child_id, args->thread_id, args->child_id, FILENAME);    
    close(fd);

    if(sem_post(sem_file)) handle_error("failed to release sem_file");

    printf("[Child#%d-Thread#%d] File %s closed!!!\n", args->child_id, args->thread_id, FILENAME);


    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

void childProcess(int child_id) {
    /* TODO: each child process notifies the main process that it
     * is ready, then waits to be notified from the main in order
     * to start. As long as the main process does not notify a
     * termination event [hint: use sem_getvalue() here], the child
     * process repeatedly creates m threads that execute function
     * thread_function() and waits for their completion. When a
     * notification has arrived, the child process notifies the main
     * process that it is about to terminate, and releases any
     * shared resources before exiting. */
    sem_wait(sem_processes);

    int i;
    pthread_t threads[M];
    while(running)
    {
        for(i = 0; i < M; i++)
            if(pthread_create(threads+i, NULL, &thread_function, NULL)) handle_error("Failed to create pthread");
        for(; i > 0; i ++)
            if(pthread_join(threads[i], NULL)) handle_error("Failed to join pthread");
    }
    _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void mainProcess() {
    /* TODO: the main process waits for all the children to start,
     * it notifies them to start their activities, and sleeps
     * for some time t. Once it wakes up, it notifies the children
     * to end their activities, and waits for their termination.
     * Finally, it calls the parseOutput() method and releases
     * any shared resources. */
    int i;
    unsigned t_left = T;
    pid_t id, *childs_ids = malloc(sizeof(pid_t)*N);

    sem_processes = create_named_semaphore(SEMPROCESSESNAME, 0777, 0);

    struct sigaction act;
    memset(&act, 0, sizeof(act));
    act.sa_handler = &child_sig_handler;
    sigaction(SIGTERM, &act, NULL);

    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        id = fork();
        if(id < 0)
            handle_error("Fork failed");
        if(id == 0)
            childProcess(i);
        childs_ids[i] = id;
    }
    for(; i > 0; i--)
        sem_post(sem_processes);

    //Sleeps for T seconds
    while((t_left = sleep(t_left)));

    for(; i < N; i++)
        {
            kill(childs_ids[i], SIGTERM);
        }

    int status;
    for(; i>0; i--)
        if(wait(&status)< 0) handle_error("wait failed");
    parseOutput();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // arguments
    if (argc > 1) n = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (argc > 2) m = atoi(argv[2]);
    if (argc > 3) t = atoi(argv[3]);

    // initialize the file
    init_file(FILENAME);

    /* TODO: initialize any semaphore needed in the implementation, and
     * create N children where the i-th child calls childProcess(i); then
     * the main process executes function mainProcess() once all the
     * children have been created */
    mainProcess();

    if(sem_close(sem_processes)) handle_error("failed to close sem_processes");
    if(sem_close(sem_file)) handle_error("failed to close sem_file");
    if(sem_unlink(SEMPROCESSESNAME)) handle_error("failed to unlink sem_processes");
    if(sem_unlink(SEMFILENAME)) handle_error("failed to unlink sem_file");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

And here is the output on the shell:

```
[Main] Child 0 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 1 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 2 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 3 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 4 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 5 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 6 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 7 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 8 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 9 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 10 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 11 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 12 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 13 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 14 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 15 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 16 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 17 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 18 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 19 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 20 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 21 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 22 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 23 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 24 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 25 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 26 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 27 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 28 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 29 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 30 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 31 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 32 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 33 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 34 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 35 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 36 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 37 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 38 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 39 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 40 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 41 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 42 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 43 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 44 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 45 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 46 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 47 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 48 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 49 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 50 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 51 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 52 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 53 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 54 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 55 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 56 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 57 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 58 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 59 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 60 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 61 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 62 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 63 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 64 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 65 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 66 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 67 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 68 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 69 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 70 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 71 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 72 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 73 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 74 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 75 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 76 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 77 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 78 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 79 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 80 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 81 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 82 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 83 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 84 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 85 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 86 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 87 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 88 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 89 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 90 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 91 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 92 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 93 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 94 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 95 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 96 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 97 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 98 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] Child 99 accessed file accesses.log 0 times
[Main] ===> The process that accessed the file most often is 0 (0 accesses)
```

Also here is common.h

```
#include <errno.h>

#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>



// macros for handling errors

#define handle_error_en(en, msg)    do { errno = en; perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

#define handle_error(msg)           do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)
```

Comment: Bay steps - create ONE process that creates ONE thread.  What happens?

Comment: Still 0 accesses and nothing written

Comment: off-topic, but you may want to know that stdout is line-buffered. IOW, if the printf() statement includes a newline (\n), there's no need to call fflush().

Also, you seem to call fflush(fd), which isn't legal C. Do you compile with max warning levels?

Comment: Thank you for the offtopic. I did not know that \n caused the flush of the buffer. I removed fflush(fd)

Comment: please post the contents of the homegrown header file: `common.h`

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  the posted code causes the compiler to output over 30 error and warning messages.  Of special interest, there are a lot of error messages about 'nested functions'  Which, hopefully neans some early function is missing the closing brace '}'.

Comment: you can save/eliminate a lot of calls to `fflush( stdout );`  by ending the format string in the calls to `printf()` with a '\n'

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks ( `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` ) via a single blank line.  2) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  3) follow the axiom:  *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.* 4) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank line (be consistent)

Comment: there is a long line of functions to NOT use in a signal handler.  Amongst those nono functions is `printf()`

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `calloc` `malloc` `realloc`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  IF not successful, call `perror()` to output your error message and the text reason the system, thinks the function failed to `stderr()`, then cleanup, then exit the program

Comment: regarding: `        printf("[Main] Child %d accessed file %s %d times\n", i, FILENAME, access_stats[i]);`  The macros `__func__`  and `__line__` (check capitalization) would work much better than trying write in the function names

Comment: variable (and parameter) names should indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both).  variable names like `n`, `m`, `t`, are meaningless even in the current context.

Comment: Never access beyond `argv[0]` with out first checking `argc` to assure the command line parameters were actually entered by the user.  If the correct number of parameters were not entered, then output a `USAGE` statement to `stderr` indicating what the expected parameters should be:  Similar to: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE: %s [parm1] [parm2] [parm3]\n", argv[0] );`  Since you know what the parameters actually mean (sadly, it is not obvious from the code) you can use much better names than `parm1`, etc

Comment: to assure that the argv[] values are actually numbers, suggest using `strtol()` rather than atoi()`  as `strtol()` will indicate if an error occurred.

Comment: it is best, for flexibility, etc, to separate the struct definition from a `typedef` for that struct

Comment: many of the C library functions can fail, including `pthread_create()` so the code should be checking any/every such C library function calls for errors

Comment: the call to `pthread_create()` is sending a NULL parameter to the thread function.  However, the thread_function() is expecting a parameter with an actual value.  AND since this parameter is not being allocated from the heap, within the `thread_function()`, the call to `free( x );` is trying to return to the heap an allocation that was never allocated.

Comment: I compiled with warnings on and now there's just 3 rather harmless ones. I'm sorry for poor indentation and formatting, but most of the code is not mine, is tested and works. I only added synchronization, i.e. TODO sections and the signal handler.  The problem should  be in there

Answer (score 0):

The thread function needed an argument of type thread_args_t and I was passing NULL. I do not know even why it did never raise segmentation fault. With proper input to pthread_create, everything works fine.